# Team System Dev Edition doesn't recognize project type

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I currently use VS 2008 Professional, but I'm trying to get Team System Developer Edition working in a Virtual Machine to evaluate it. However, when I try to open any of my current solutions, it gives me the following message:

'Z:\Samples\ChartControl\WebSamples' cannot be opened because its project type () is not supported by this version of Visual Studio.

Any idea what this is trying to tell me? Why is it not recognizing the project type?

Comment: Were the solution and projects created in earlier version of Visual Studio? What language was used?

Comment: Most were created with 2008 Professional, some are Microsoft sample apps. All VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because you have extra project types on your Visual Studio that are not included in the TFS build.  An example would be MVC project types.  Why are you opening projects in TFS?  TFS should be simply source control, bug lists and a build server and not be handling projects in Visual Studio

Also check that TFS is at the same .NET version as your dev environemnt.  If you're wanting to create automated builds from a project that is .NET 3.5 SP1, make sure TFS is at the same level.

Comment: Sorry - not TFS; Team System, the client side of the team suite. I'll fix the original question. I'll check the service pack as well.